# The number_next in ir_sequence can not be changed when they change directly on database base

Tags: database, odoo

When I change directly the value of number_next on ir_sequence of Sales order ,The Sequence in interface cannot change ? Why? Thanks.

Comment: are you changing it from the view or from the database directly?

Comment: from the database directly